# in flask it is possible to render a template outside the app?

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask and would like to render a template from a directory outside the app. does it work anyway?
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

A flask application will look for a templates folder in the same directory as the application. You can however specify a different folder:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='path/of/template/folder')
```

Comment: ok, but then I have the template folder only outside the app. Is there also the possibility to address both templates folder, one in the app and one outside the app?